# Getting friend's groups using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm working on a Facebook App to list my friends based on the group I'm in.

Say like, I'm member of group named X. I want to list the friends who are also there in group X.

The below query doesn't seems to work.
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,birthday,groups&access_token=a_Token

NB: I have selected all necessary permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with an FQL query

```
 select uid from group_member where gid = xxxx and uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me() )
```

where xxxx is the group id

alternatively to return all your groups this could be :

```
 where gid in (select gid from group_member WHERE uid = me());
```

This would simply return the uids of your friends. You could then use a multi-query to return more information about them

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/